# how to write a (not from dataframe)file in aws s3 using spark scala at specific location(by creating location automatically if it doesnt exists)

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Can someone please help me in writing the file to s3 to a specific location.

I have some properties/values in my scala program and I need to write them to a file at specific location(by creating directories if not available already)

```
file1:
val val1 = "abc"
val val2 = "xyz"

file2:
val val1 = "abcdef"
val val2 = "abcxyz"
```

need a solution to write above values into s3 location by creating directories if not exists.

```
s3://instance_name/<create_directory if not exists>/filename
```

I am new to aws s3 and need some help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the usage of Spark here ...

Comment: also using the AWS SDK is well documented of course: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/getting-started.html

Comment: I have gone through the above link but I don't see examples related to how to write into file by creating it.

Comment: ??? there are no files in S3, and examples of course exist: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html